# Do I need to apply for a new Australian eVisitor visa if I have lost my passport?

Tags: passports, australia, e-visas

I am due to travel to Australia on March  6, to join a cruise. 
I applied some time ago, and was granted, an eVisitor visa.
Recently I lost my passport, so I applied for, and was granted, a new one.
I now have a new passport with a new number.
Do I need to apply for a new eVisitor visa?

Answer (score 4):

Your e-Visa is linked to your passport number [Australian E-visa got my passport number wrong](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/115835/australian-e-visa-got-my-passport-number-wrong?r=SearchResults) All you need to do is tell Australian Immigration that your passport details have changed. You can do this online here https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/change-in-situation/passport-details